# SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) installation failed

Tags: ssis

installing the Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe
on a Windows 10 PC, with Visual Studio 2019 already installed,
I got this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Here the last part of the log file:

> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i319: Applied execute package: ISVsix,
> result: 0x80131500, restart: None
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to
> execute EXE package. [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i329: Removed
> package dependency provider: ISVsix, package: ISVsix
> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsix,
> from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7
> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i326: Removed dependency:
> {ab4889d7-79a3-40dc-9c9e-ccbeca99d453} on package provider:
> ISVsixPreInstall, package ISVsixPreInstall
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction:
> Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services
> Projects Pre Install (id: ISVsixPreInstall)
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i000:
> MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall
> progress: 14 [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i301: Applying rollback
> package: ISVsixPreInstall, action: Uninstall, path:
> C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\BB952DD82F1ADAE438C26E4EE6C94F84C07CB447\ISVsixPreInstall.exe,
> arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\BB952DD82F1ADAE438C26E4EE6C94F84C07CB447\ISVsixPreInstall.exe"
> /instanceIds:"2904af6a,6f5e5ef0"
> /log:"C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20210531194052_0_ISVsixPreInstall.log"
> /u' [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i000:
> MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft
> SQL Server Integration Services Projects Pre Install (id:
> ISVsixPreInstall) [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i319: Applied
> rollback package: ISVsixPreInstall, result: 0x0, restart: None
> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i329: Removed package dependency
> provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package: ISVsixPreInstall
> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i351: Removing cached package:
> ISVsixPreInstall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\BB952DD82F1ADAE438C26E4EE6C94F84C07CB447
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i000:
> MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall
> progress: 100 [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i330: Removed bundle
> dependency provider: {ab4889d7-79a3-40dc-9c9e-ccbeca99d453}
> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i352: Removing cached bundle:
> {ab4889d7-79a3-40dc-9c9e-ccbeca99d453}, from path:
> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{ab4889d7-79a3-40dc-9c9e-ccbeca99d453}
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction:
> Bundle action failed: Unknown error (0x80131500) (0x80131500)
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]i399: Apply complete, result:
> 0x80131500, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
> [5CD0:4D80][2021-05-31T19:48:12]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening
> url:
> C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20210531194052.log
> [5CD0:4D80][2021-05-31T20:04:01]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening
> url:
> C:\Users\Luigi\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20210531194052.log

And here only the ERROR rows:

> [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: Error 0x80131500: Process
> returned error: 0x80131500 [0AEC:278C][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: Error
> 0x80131500: Failed to execute EXE package.
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to
> configure per-machine EXE package. ...
> [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to
> execute EXE package. ... [5CD0:13EC][2021-05-31T19:42:29]e000:
> MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Unknown error
> (0x80131500) (0x80131500)

Answer (score 5):

After hours trying to figure out why my installation was failing, I found a post where someone suggested to repair Visual Studio installations via VS Installer, I did it, of course this meant that the enviroment was going to be restored as new, but it solved my issue.

I hope this could help you friend, have a nice day!
[image]

Comment: This solved my issue as well (running VS 2019 repair).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by following:
Installed all .Net Framework versions 4.X with
[Visual Studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgl5e.png)

Answer (score 2):

If someone has the same problem in 2023 with Win11 :I have updated to the latest NET Framework 4.8.1 (using Win11) and after restart of Win11 the installer did his job perfect an VS2022 opens the SSIS files correctly

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason of failure was my PC was missing some of the target packs. No need to Repair the installation.

I installed .NET 4, 4.5 and 4.7 targeting packs from VS installation media and the SSIS installation succeeded smoothly.

Comment: Similar for me with VS2022, except I just had to install .NET FW 4.8.1 & Target Pack

Answer (score -2):

I also tried to install Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe on a Windows 10 PC, with Visual Studio 2019 already installed.

Try running the .exe file with "Administrator" privileges.

My error code was "Unknown error (0xffffffff) (0xFFFFFFFF)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).