# Microsoft SSIS SQL Server Integration Services Installation Error Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I am trying to deploy the SSIS developer toolkit to my Visual Studio 2019 instance. I tried yesterday's download as well as a new download today with the same result. Details are below. I will also look at another [Stack post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67778324/ssis-sql-server-integration-services-installation-failed) and see if this helps in the meantime.

I don't have the experience to interpret the log file.  Can someone assist?

> MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Unknown error (0x80131500) (0x80131500)

Error message result from Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe

[image]

Visual Studio 2019 version information - Updated to latest version

[image]

LOG File - See subsequent posts for full log file. Please note log file order. Stack posts it out of order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68538249/7763687) corrected my error message.  Initiating a "repair" via the Visual Studio Installer apparently fixed the problem.

I have no explanation as to what was fixed.  There was no indication that anything had been corrected by the repair.

Additionally, my installation of Visual Studio 2019 was only 1 day old when I tried to install SSIS extension.

I will leave the original log files part 1-4 in case someone knows how to read through that and fix the issue.

Comment: I now actively discourage building solutions in SSIS, and this is one of the reasons. The tool installer is buggy and unreliable. Now that you have it working there's no guarantee it will stay working. See here for some of my frustrations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package/47645278#47645278

Comment: It’s a legacy project that we’ve had around since 2016. Believe me…it is not my favorite thing.  We have a plan to kill it but getting the boss to give us time to do it…yet another frustration. I will take a look at your link. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: No need to repair, on VS 2022 I just installed .NET FW 4.8.1 and target pack